# Object map Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a object map in JavaScript and I have to read it.

The object map is:

```
  network[0]
  Object {dpi: "user2"}
```

I have used this to read the key:

```
demp=Object.keys(network[0]);
sourceNodeFirewall = demp[0];
```

But I'm not able to read the value ("user2").

I know that I can do this:

```
network[0].dpi
```

in order to have `user2`, but during a for cycle I have no idea to do it, in addition that the key can change in any value.

I cannot put the real code because it is very complicate but an simple example is:

The object is set in this way:

```
 var network = {};
network[$("#0B").val()] = $("#0BB").val();
```

Where I have a key and I value.

After that I wish to get the value and the key.

Answer (score 0):

*demp* stores all key of the object, You need to access the property from the *network[0]* object.

```js
var network = [{dpi: "user2"}];
demp = Object.keys(network[0]);
console.log(network[0][demp[0]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access an object's properties by indexing into it with square brackets:

```js
var network = [{dpi: "user2"}];

console.log(network[0]);

var demp = Object.keys(network[0]);
var sourceNodeFirewall = demp[0];
var propValue = network[0][demp[0]];

console.log(propValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop you need to iterate over each key in the map, and to access the value just lookup the map with that key as the index.

```js
var network = {
  dpi: "user2"
}
for (var key in network) {
  console.log(network[key]);
}
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer. You are answering for readers and not for OP

Answer (score 0):

As you referred to a `for` loop, here what I think you are looking for:

```js
const obj = {
  dpi: "user2"
};

for(key in obj){
  console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

Or maybe using a `forEach`:

```js
const obj = {
  dpi: "user2"
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(
  key => console.log(obj[key])
)
```